# Can Matlab use multiple processors for plots and interactions in plots?

Tags: matlab, plot, multiprocessing

I am analyzing EMG data in my research lab. One of the steps is to calculate a continuous wavelet transformation of the dataset (size ~80000). Therefore, I use Matlab with the wavelet toolbox and "cwt" to plot a 3D-scalogram.

The calculation takes a lot of time and any interaction like 3D-rotation (which is very important to see different aspects of the data) is nearly impossible.

The resource-monitor shows that only one of my hexa-core processor is working. I use parallel computing for other calculations and haven't found any solution or even a similiar question like this.

Is there anything I can do to activate multicore support for plots?

Comment: This is not really an answer *per se* because while I don't think parallel computing will help you here, you can improve performance in other ways.  First, make sure the data you're plotting is sampled at the appropriate rate: use `decimate` to reduce it if possible. Second, select portions of the full matrix to plot and manipulate in 3D rather than the entire thing (if possible).  The less data you give the figure, the better the perfomance will be.

Comment: unfortunately I can't resample my data, otherwise I would lose important details. furthermore, if I only select portions I can't figure out real artefacts which have a high percentage of energy in respect to the whole dataset

Answer (score 1):

I'll hazard an educated guess and plump for the answer *No* to your question *Is there anything I can do to activate multicore support for plots?*

Matlab can certainly use multiple cores for its computations. Many of its intrinsic functions are already multi-threaded and will use any available cores without the programmer (or user) having to do take any special measures.  For your own computations you can use the Parallel Compute Toolbox.

However, unless you have some very special graphics hardware (and if you do why didn't you mention it ?) your display shows you why only one processor is being used when you interact with your 3D plots -- somewhere between the screen and the hardware of your computer there is a bottleneck through which the outputs of all those cores are squeezed into one stream of bits and bytes for presentation.

Your experience is consistent with that bottleneck being the Matlab visualisation routines, I think it is safe to conclude from the evidence you present, that the Mathworks haven't multi-threaded the routines which compute the new screen positions of each element in a plot as you rotate it, or any of the other processing that goes on to turn the results of your analyses into a picture or pictures.  If they did parallelise those routines, that would shift the bottleneck but not remove it.

To remove the bottleneck you would have to have a way for different Matlab threads to separately address different parts of your screen; I see no evidence that Matlab has that capability.  Google will find you a ton of references to *parallel rendering* but I see no sign that Matlab currently implements any aspect of this.

I'll just add, in response to your comment where you write *unfortunately I can't resample my data* that you should be mindful that Matlab's visualisation routines are resampling your data for presentation unless you are only visualising datasets with numbers of samples less than the number of pixels available.  If you visualise a time series with 80000 samples on a display with 2000 pixels horizontally, something has got to give.

You might get better graphics performance and superior understanding if you take charge of that resampling yourself.

Comment: He's not plotting a time series with 80000 points, though.  He's plotting analysis of that time series.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what he's plotting.  Without further input I remain suspicious that he is letting Matlab downsample large datasets for visualisation.  Perhaps OP will come back and enlighten us.

Comment: @BenVoigt A continuous wavelet transform will give out the same number of points put in (in the time domain that is; if time is columns, rows is (roughly) frequency, so you're turning a vector into a matrix). Downsampling before plotting (to a sampling rate suitable to whatever scale is being visualized) is my recommendation too.

Comment: @tmpearce: Sure, but with a matrix, you're more concerned with the total number of pixels on the screen, not just horizontal resolution.  My screen can easily display a heatmap with over 80000 points (that's only 400x200).  And 80000 triangles shouldn't even make the video card break a sweat.

Comment: @BenVoigt If the timeseries is originally `1x80000`, and he's examining 200 frequencies, the output he's visualizing is `200x80000`: you preserve the time information in each row, so it really is a 1D resolution problem.  If you are able to average in time (or put a different portion of the original vector into each row) you could go from `1x80000` to `200x400` provided you only care about a single frequency.

Comment: sorry for the delay - time for some "enlightening". I have recorderd EMG data with a sampling frequency of 2kHz over 40.5sec -> 81000 values. the CWT runs with a 10Hz scale between 10-1000 Hz, so 100x81000 coefficients are calculated.
@High Performance Mark: this is what i am doing: `[c,s] = cwt(emgData(1:81000,5),10:10:1000,'morl','3Dplot');` Therefore, the result is a 3D-time-frequency plot.
I tried to `decimate` the dataset, but then I lost important information (=artefacts, which I want to figure out). It seems that there is no easy way to handle this. Thanks anyway to all the fast help

Comment: Well, if simple (?) decimation doesn't work you will have to devise some approach to downsampling-for-visualisation which neither hides important information nor creates misleading artefacts.  And that's a whole new ballgame which is, as you observe, not necessarily easy.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab plotting performance is pretty bad, it's more focused on customizability than performance.  Using MEX to run some native C++ code to plot the data with OpenGL will likely be much much faster.